# how to get Distinct or UNIQUE string lines from json file

Tags: python, json, regex, string, twitter

i have json file of tweets which contains following data.

ID, FUll name, TEXT , Timestamp , URL USER, fullname , retweets etc

Each json file is UNIQUE But in some jsons ['TEXT'] field  is same.

i want to remove those json files which contains same tweet in ['text'] field.

here is example of my json file.. Both json are from different users but they tweets same text.

```
    {
  'fullname': 'آدم',
  'id': '772154564711768064',
  'likes': '5',
  'replies': '0',
  'retweets': '0',
  'text': '#GoNawazGoNawaz\n''This woman has realized the truth....hope nation realizes it ''too.... \n''#PanamaLeaks\n''#GoNawazGoNawazpic.twitter.com/6m7nWgldQp',
  'timestamp': '2016-09-03T19:29:28',
  'url': '/NaikOlad/status/772154564711768064',
  'user': 'NaikOlad'
}{
  'fullname': 'سلمان اعوان',
  'id': '772156567542231040',
  'likes': '0',
  'replies': '0',
  'retweets': '0',
  'text': '#GoNawazGoNawaz\n''This woman has realized the truth....hope nation realizes it ''too.... \n''#PanamaLeaks\n''#GoNawazGoNawazpic.twitter.com/L2tZUOVs1z',
  'timestamp': '2016-09-03T19:37:26',
  'url': '/SaluBhai420/status/772156567542231040',
  'user': 'SaluBhai420'
}
```

Comment: both are different jsons right?

Comment: @whoami yeah. both tweets from different persons.

Comment: okay  give me sometime

Comment: The tweets are not identical since they have different IDs and URLs. Only the text is identical. What have you tried so far to reach your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.Dataframe()
df1 = df1.append(first_tweet_json,ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append(second_tweet_json,ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['text'],keep='last')
print(df1)
```

Comment: pip install pandas

Comment: you have to install the pandas package first

Comment: i did same as you say but still there are duplicate tweets.

Comment: i just need **['text']** in my json file but it should not b duplicate.

Comment: so you want to eliminate the jsons which have duplicate text am i right?

Comment: your final result should be jsons that dont have duplicate tweets which have the same text right ?